# Regex to get first 6 and last 4 characters of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use regex instead of string.replace() to get the first 6 chars of a string and the last 4 chars of the same string and substitute it with another character: `&` for example. The string is always with 16 chars. Im doing some research but i never worked with regex before. Thanks

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to use substring?

Comment: In your case job done by regex will be significantly slower than by substring

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Is your question "get 2 separate parts of string as single match with regex" ?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: This site has a fantastic quickstart/tutorial. http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Seriously, don't use regexes for such trivial problems. It's like nuking a mosquito: the job is done, but you put far too much effort in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you prefer to use regular expression, you could use the following. The dot `.` will match any character except a newline sequence, so you can specify `{n}` to match exactly n times and use beginning/end of string anchors.

```
String r = Regex.Replace("123456foobar7890", @"^.{6}|.{4}$", 
                m => new string('&', m.ToString().Length));

Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "&&&&&&foobar&&&&"
```

If you want to **invert** the logic, replacing the middle portion of your string you can use [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds).

```
String r = Regex.Replace("123456foobar7890", @"(?<=^.{6}).{6}",
                m => new string('&', m.ToString().Length));

Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "123456&&&&&&7890"
```

Comment: Could you use that to "123456foobar7890"->"&&&&&&foobar&&&&"? I'm thinking the OP wants to show that there are 16 chars, but hide some of them.

Comment: Aha! Found it: `Regex re = new Regex(@"^.{6}|.{4}$"); String r = re.Replace("123456foobar7890", m => new string('&', m.ToString().Length));` - there might be a more compact way to do that in a C# later than I have to hand (3.5).

Comment: @hwnd Thanks, got your point, but if i want to invert the logic, for example, show the 6 first chars, replace the 'foobar' as & and show the last 4 chars again?

Comment: @hwnd foreach char, 123456&&&&&&7891